# unregister client script from Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui

I register a jQuery UI datepicker in Asp.Net page using .Net `ScriptManager` class.

```
private void registerDatePicker(TextBox tb)
{
      if (tb != null)
      {
         ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "registerDatePicker" + tb.ID, "registerDatePicker('" + tb.ClientID + "');", true);
      }
}
```

So once I registered, I want to unregistered the script from the page. How can I do that ?

Thanks

After @StackOverflowException answer,

The reason I want to unregister the script is, I have few `TextBox` controls which will be created dynamically and hooked with date picker. Not only a datepicker is registered,a dialog and validator scripts are also registered. So the script is becoming bigger and bigger in a page. So once I used the control, If I am no longer use the control then I want to remove the associated registered script.

**Note** The controls are created and added in a `Table`

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery makes this so simple (and compactly) that you really shouldn't do it on server-side (if I understand what you're doing).

Just add a class (like `date-picker`) to the text boxes that should use date pickers, then put a single line of code on your HTML page:

```
$('date-picker').datepicker();
```

Every suitable textbox on your page will use the jQuery `datepicker`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no unregister for such scripts. May I ask why you are trying to unregister?. They are usually registered on every postback (asynchronous or synchronous )  for stuff like hooking up date picker to textbox if done from code-behind. If it's something that you want just on the first load, like displaying a message,  you could do something like this

```
if(!IsPostBack){

// register script

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may be handled in the PageRequestManager endRequest event.